# Which one is the better choice

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

idealistic vs ideal
1.He thinks they’re extremely idealistic, for all their pragmatism.
2.He thinks they’re extremely ideal, for all their pragmatism.

Comment: Have you looked up both words in the dictionary?

Comment: #1 comments on their ethics. #2 says they are a good selection, based on some undefined criteria. The two sentences have completely different meanings.

Comment: @KateBunting yes, and the key to this question is ideal, which I don’t understand why. i think both are fine.

Comment: So it depends on what you want to say.

Comment: @PcMan i know that the two sentences are completely different, but i am not so sure which one is more natural/common/reasonable.

Comment: @user112563 It does, indeed, depend on what you want to say. #1 would be much more likely to occur, simply because it is more common to comment on someone's viewpoint than to be selecting them for something. You tag the question as "meaning-in-context", but unfortunately you fail to provide the context wherein you wish to judge it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some grammar corrections are needed in your sentences. You shouldn't use a comma to set off "*for all their pragmatism*" because it modifies the main verb "*be(are)*" there.

The corrected ones are:

> 1.He thinks they’re extremely idealistic for all their pragmatism.

> 2.He thinks they’re extremely ideal for all their pragmatism.

The first sentence means:

> They are extremely idealistic for all their pragmatism, so they are doing everything for their own ideology and are ready, eager, willing to sacrifice so many things and even their life. So, they are idealistic.

The second sentence means:

> They are extremely ideal for all their pragmatism, so they are better than the others working for the same ideology and every ideology needs these kinds of people who are hard-working. They are really good choices for the success, plans and road map of the ideology.

That's what I understood from the two.